# how to could i set pythonhome

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04

i am new to python3 i don't know how to set PYTHONHOME in ubuntu 16.04.
i tried whereis python it show like below
this many version it show. from this how can i set pythonhome for python3.x

```
sysadmin@localoffice:~$ whereis python
     python: /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python2.7 
             /usr/bin/python3.5m-config /usr/bin/pythnfig 
             /usr/bin/python3.5m /usr/lib/python3.5 /usr/lib/python2.7 
             /etc/python /etc/python3.5 /etc/python2local/lib/python3.5 
             /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/include/python3.5 
             /usr/include/python3.5m 
            /usr/share/usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
sysadmin@localoffice:~$ echo ${PYTHONPATH}

sysadmin@localoffice:~$
```

Comment: You're asking about `PYTHONHOME` but echoing `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: @doelleri echo `${PYTHONPATH}` return empty path

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
alias python /path/to/your/python/home
```

e.g:

```
alias python /usr/bin/python2.7
```